# Karate - Trouble passing correct headers for authorization

Tags: karate

I am have some problems passing in the correct headers for my graphql endpoints

The use case in Postman:

- call requestToken endpoint to obtain sessionToken value
- requestToken response contains Key Value " and Token Value.
- For subsequent calls, I set postman headers as:
  Key = X_SESSION_TOKEN               Value = Token Value

The user case in Karate

- 1st feature 'requestToken.feature' successfully calls and stores key + tokenValue
- 2nd feature successfully defines and prints the token value
  here is my 2nd request:

  Feature: version

  ```
       Background: 
       * url 'http://api-dev.markq.com:5000/'
       * def myFeature = call read('requestToken.feature')
       * def authToken = myFeature.sessionToken
       * configure headers = { 'X_SESSION_TOKEN': authToken , 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

       Scenario: get version
       Given path 'query'
       Given text query = 
       """
       query {
       version
       }

       """

       And request { query: '#(query)' }
       When method POST
       Then status 200
       And print authToken
       And print response
  ```

I am not sure I send the headers right. Its coming back 200, but I keep getting a error 'token malformed' in the response message

Any suggestions? New at this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly this is hard to answer, a LOT depends on the specific server.

EDIT: most likely it is this change needed, explained here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions

```
* configure headers = { 'X_SESSION_TOKEN': '#(authToken)' , 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
```

2 things from experience:

- should it be `X-SESSION-TOKEN`
- add an `Accept: 'application/json'` header

And try to hardcode the headers before attempting `call` etc.

Here is an example that works for me:

```
* url 'https://graphqlzero.almansi.me/api'
* text query =
"""
{
  user(id: 1) {
    posts {
      data {
        id
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
"""
* request { query: '#(query)' }
* method post
* status 200
```

Comment: This was the ticket: * configure headers = { 'X_SESSION_TOKEN': '#(authToken)' , 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }


Thank You SO MUCH!